# Laravel 5: how to query a pivot table using Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Is there a way to use Eloquent to query a pivot table without having a model for that pivot table?

Situation: a user can own multiple businesses, and a business can be owned by multiple users. I have the following tables to deal with the many-to-many relationship.

```
| users     | businesses  | business_user |
-------------------------------------------
| id        | id          | business_id   |
| name      | name        | user_id       |
| created_at| created_at  | created_at    |
| updated_at| updated_at  | updated_at    |
```

My User.php model

```
public function businesses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My Business.php model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

1- In my controller, i'm trying to query the business_user (pivot) table to count the number of businesses the Auth user Id has.

```
select count(*) from business_user where user_id = Auth::user()->id() ;
```

2- I'm trying to query the business_user (pivot) table to get the business name for each row found in table business_user for that user id.

```
select business_user.business_id, businesses.name 
  from business_user 
  join businesses 
    on business_user.business_id = businesses.id
 where business_user.user_id     = Auth::user()->id() ;
```

I would like to query the pivot table with Eloquent, but I can't get the syntax right. Do I need a model for that business_user table?

Do some of you prefer not using Eloquent at all?

Thanks
cv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Model for a Pivot table.  Things you are asking for are  pretty straight forward.

Number of businesses the current logged in `User` has

```
echo \Auth::user()->businesses->count();
```

name of each business for current `User`

```
foreach(\Auth::user()->businesses as $business){
  echo $business->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I can't get my head around this Eloquent syntax. I just don't get it yet, but your code works! Thanks sooo much